# Can'n run the NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (Full Package) on Windows 11 with arm cpu, why?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a macbook M1PRO, and I need to debug .net2.0 and .net 3.5 codes in its Windows11 virtual machine, but I can't set up a code runtime environment。
I have installed .net framework 3.5 in the "enabling or disabling windows features" in the control panel, but its existence is still not recognized in visual studio.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kaNV.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IqI3.png)
If I don't use a simulated x64 virtual machine or another x64 computer, I just want to run all programs on one computer, how can I solve it？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a x64 VM, then you have to install windows 11 (not arm based version).

then install visual studio for windows. (again, the non arm version).

At that point, you can develop with .net framework 2.0-4.8.

You can't create, run, use, enjoy, develop .net framework asp.net applications unless you running a windows VM, and using the windows version of VS.

You can ONLY run (and develop) .net core applications on arm based, or other computers, and NOT .net framework applications.

given that you looking to develop (or work on) a x64 .net framework, and quite a older version?

Then you have to create a x64 (not arm) based VM, and install the x64 bit version of windows (again, NOT the arm based version of windows). You then install Visual Studio for windows.

The above will thus allow you to develop and work on .net framework applications, such a as asp.net .net framework based application.